# Special Quantum Gate

Tags: quantum-computation

Given $\alpha|1\rangle+\beta|0\rangle$, to transform to $|\phi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$ , we use Quantum NOT gate:

NOT = $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

For $\alpha|0\rangle-\beta|1\rangle$, what kind of gate do we need to have to transform to $|\phi\rangle$ ? Is it ok that we construct a gate as:

A = $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Comment: This is the [Pauli Z-gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Pauli-Z_gate).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're representing $|0\rangle \simeq \binom{1}{0}$ and $|1\rangle \simeq \binom{0}{1}$. If you are, then you would be correct.

Comment: Will there be a name for this gate ?